# Cant create laravel version 10 project but i do have PHP version 8.2

Tags: php, laravel, xampp, composer-php, laragon

I have this php version in my desktop

```
PHP 8.2.2 (cli) (built: Jan 31 2023 21:19:11) (ZTS Visual C++ 2019 x64)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.2.2, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
```

and i try to create laravel project with this code

composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel:^10.0 testa-project

but it said i can not create laravel 10 project because of this

```
Could not find package laravel/laravel with version 10.0 in a version 
installable using your PHP version, PHP extensions and Composer version.
```

anyone know the solution ?

i have try this solution but nothing works

- change php version
- switching from laragon to xampp or the opposite

Comment: Which PHP version is used by Composer? How is your problem related to Laragon?

Comment: What composer version do you have installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to install laravel globally using laravel install by doing this `composer global require laravel/installer` then use this `laravel new your-app-name` to install the newest laravel. I make my app name to be temp, then move it directly to public folder after installing the project.

Comment: i already did that it seems like the php version that downloaded from php.net/downloads.php
is kinda bad